# Identifying what part of the code is responsible for making the program do what the user say in the number of tests

Tags: java

This program is about a user being prompted to enter how many tests they want the average of and then the program will ask them to input however many they said. I am having trouble identifying how the code does that. What makes it know to return as many inputs as the user asks. Thank you!

I looked at the while function but that seems to only be if the user inputs something like 0 or a negative number (I think).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class average {

    public static String getLetterGrade(double average) {
        if (average < 60) {
            return "F";
        } else if (average < 70) {
            return "D";
        } else if (average < 80) {
            return "C";
        } else if (average < 90){
            return "B";
        }
         else;{
            return "A";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome, please type your first name. ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome, please type your last name. ");
        String last = scan.nextLine();
        int n;
        System.out.println("How many tests would you like the average of?");
        n = scan.nextInt();

        while(n<0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
            System.out.println("How many tests would you like the average 
                of?");
            n = scan.nextInt();
       }

       double sum = 0, grade;
       System.out.println("Enter " + n + " scores.");
       for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
           grade = scan.nextDouble();
           sum += grade;
       }
       double average = (sum/n);
       System.out.println("Okay " + name.charAt(0) + last.charAt(0) + ", your 
       average score is " + (average));
       System.out.println("Your letter grade is a " + 
       getLetterGrade(average));

    }

}
```

There are no errors in this program it runs and does what it is suppose to do.

Comment: Did you look at the for loop beneath the while *loop* (not function)? `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` - `i` starts at `0` and increases until it is one less than `n` (if the user says they want to input `4` scores and it looped until `i` was equal to `n`, then it would loop `5` times since `i` starts at `0`). There may be no errors, but immediately preceding an `else` statement with a semicolon (`;`) will most likely produce unexpected results.

Comment: Jonny you're a genius thank you so much!